# How is each page table entry of 24 bits here?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging, page-tables

Diagram shows virtual and physical address. Its a multi level paging.
[A multilevel paging diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzC4m.png)
I understand that first page table can be located by adding ptbr + p1 bits= ultimatelty locating first PT using 36 bits...
But how can each PT store only 24 bits ? How can the second PT be located if only info this 24 bits gives is the frame number it wants and not the actual location. I think that should be 32 bits but correct answer is 24 and I'm not understanding this.

Comment: Well, if you have 2^24 pages like you are showing, surely the index of such page would fit into 24 bits?

Comment: So are the other bits put to zero ? Because only 24 bits are not enough to access the physical address, It requires 36 bits in total